# Autoresponsive design in DIV

Tags: html, css, window-resize

Well i'm working on this site:

http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/865/2838074395.jpg

But when i resize the browser i have a problem with the DIV with the logo:

http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/865/9052667407.jpg

Anyone has any idea what can i do for the div with the logo?

Here is the code:

```
<div id="container2" class="clearfix">
    <div class="isotope-block">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/wall/img-1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>

    <div class="isotope-block">
      <div><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/wall/img-1.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="isotope-block logoWall">
       <div class="logoWallBackground"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="isotope-block">
      <div><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/wall/img-1.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="isotope-block">
      <div><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/wall/img-1.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
    </div>
</div>


    .isotope-block {
    margin:0;
    -webkit-border-radius:0;
    -moz-border-radius:0;
    border-radius:0;
    -webkit-box-shadow:none;
    -moz-box-shadow:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    font-size:0;
    line-height:0;
    width:7.6%;
    float: left;
}

.logoWallBackground {
    background:url("../img/wall/img-logo.jpg") no-repeat scroll center center / 96% 92% #1B1B1B;
    height:10%;
    width:100%;
}

.clearfix {
*zoom:1
}

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    display:table;
    content:"";
    line-height:0
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear:both
}
```

Comment: I edited the postwith with some css

Comment: `.isotope-block` has a `width: 7.6%`. That's why

Comment: But if i don't put that i can't put the widht to the divs... the logowall has
.logoWall{
 width:22.8%;
}

Comment: Try giving us a live example. The code you gave us [looks nothing like what you have](http://jsfiddle.net/WzXFz/)